# Difference between 入れる{いれる} and つける when expressing 'switch on'

Tags: word-choice

- 入れる{いれる} can mean *to turn on (a switch, etc.)*
- 点ける{つける} can mean *to turn on; to switch on; to light up*

I do not see the difference. When would I use which?

---

「入れる{いれる}」と「点ける{つける}」の違{ちが}いは何ですか。

Answer (score 1):

When you are talking about turn on light, you should say つける.

> [電気]{でんき}をつける。

[電気]{でんき} is the common way to say electricity lighting, by the way.

つける also can apply to any kind of stuffs.

> エアコンをつける。 (Turn on the air conditioner.)
>   テレビをつける。 (Turn on the TV.)
>   パソコンをつける。 (Turn on the PC.)
>   [電源]{でんげん}をつける。 (Turn on the power.)

入{い}れる is sometimes interchangeable with つける, but it only works with some specific objects. The following sentences are good examples of 入{い}れる.

> エアコンを入{い}れる。
>   [電源]{でんげん}を入{い}れる。

You could say テレビを入{い}れる, but it is not common. You should say テレビをつける which is much more common. The same goes for パソコン.

Answer (score -1):

入れる　literally means "to put (into)."
Thus 電源を入れる = to turn on the power.

つける is used for lighting.
Thus 照明を点ける = to turn on the light.

Comment: What about 火を点ける and 火を入れる?

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why 電気をつける is valid either.

Comment: Isn't 電気 in that sense just a form of synecdoche (or metonymy whichever) to refer to lights?

Comment: @Earthing:  火を点ける = ignite.

火を入れる = set on fire (used for furnaces and heaters.)

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie: 電気をつける is an expression (somewhat dated) meaning "to turn on the electric light" from the days when the main electric apparatuses were electric bulbs.

Comment: @ssb I don't know, but according to 日本国語大辞典, the use of 電気 to mean electric light comes from abbreviating 電気灯（でんきとう）.

Comment: I don't think つける is only used for lighting. At least you can say エアコンをつける(turn on the air conditioner.)

Comment: @Takashi: Hmm. It is true that "つける" is sometimes used to mean "to turn on" as in テレビをつける (to turn on the TV), ガスをつける (to turn on the gas range), etc.